# Best way to implement parameterize scenarios in Cucumber?

Tags: automated-testing, cucumber, bdd

I found two ways of parameterize, Which one is correct from below

1. Given Go to < url >
2. Given Go to "url"

Angular brackets or double quotes, which is the right way of using?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Please read the documentation: https://cucumber.io/docs/reference

- The <> are used only for Scenario Outline examples.
- The "" double-quotes are not really needed too parameterize, it just makes it easier to see and read what the parameter is in a sentence, but all the reference examples do not use them.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned in details how you have implemented or intent to be implemented. [I will suggest to have practice to add more details for your question.]

- Seems you wanted to give input of URL to particular step
- In both above step if you are directly going to keep actual URL then It will not make any major difference

**Good practices:**

- What you can do for giving input of URL, you should provide it after/below your this step definition.
- Instead of hard-coded value in step itself
- Even better option would be if you can fetch that input from different test_data file